# Is there any way to work with subprojects within Github?

Tags: git, github

What I have in mind is to create a directory tree for a Project and its Subprojects.

As I am pretty new to using Github, I've been doing a lot of research on file organization and control with git, but I haven't found anything like a solution I have in mind. In fact, I don't know if it's possible or recommended.
My idea is to create a root repository to group my projects for example in Python, where the final structure would look like:

```
Python
- Python/SubProject1
- Python/SubProject2
- Python/SubProjectN
```

However, when I start the git control in the root `git init Python` and also in any of the subprojects `git init ProjectN` and send them to Github, the subdirectories become unavailable for reading and empty as well. I also saw that there is a way to work with submodule inside the root, but when I try create one I get an error:

> ProjectN already exists and is not a valid git repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it you have two options submodules or subtree. I've been using submodules a lot recently and that is a way to put git repos inside a git repo and track which commit of the submodules repo your root repo is using.
If you need to contribute code back to the subprojects you should use submodules, otherwise go for subtree.

Submodules is quite tricky to learn how to handle. I've made a set of git scripts that will make it easier. Right now only works on git for windows. Take a look at https://github.com/jlovs/git-scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [submodule](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules), although I don't think the submodule can reside under the root directory in git.

A workaround is

1) Use .gitignore to ignore SubProjectN so you can call `git init` inside SubProjectN.

2) Use symlink to link SubProjectN and the root together.